# C# .NET and direct object collections

Tags: c#, collections

Hey all is there a collection type like arrayList which i can add an object to using an ID?

effectively as the title of my post sugests a Direct object collection. so for example:

```
DirectCollection.addAt(23, someobject);
```

and

```
DirectCollection.getAt(23);
```

etc etc

i know arraylist is usable in that case but i have to generate the initial entry with a null reference object and if if the object has an ID like 23 i have to generate 22 other entries just to add it which is clearly impractical.

basically using the object position value as a unique ID.

Any thoughts?

Many thanks.

Comment: @Marco I'm always amused by these "Pick me, pick me!" comments!

Comment: @Marco I think there's a balance between being condescending and welcoming, and while your intent may be to be helpful, it seems to fall a little bit on the condescending side. (And certainly your reply is extraordinarily condescending) Gelion has been a member for 11 days and his profile shows no indication that he has neglected choosing a answer to accept. Maybe if he had a few outstanding answered questions your point would jive a little more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Dictionary<int, YourType>`
Like this:

```
var p = new Dictionary<int, YourType>();
p.Add(23, your_object);
YourType object_you_just_added = p[23];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [Dictionary](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary)

The code for your example would be very simple:

```
Dictionary<int, AType> directCollection = new Dictionary<int, AType>();
directCollection.Add(23, someObjectOfAType);
AType anObject = directCollection[23];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<int, YourType>
```

It allows you to add/get/remove items with a given key and non continuous ranges.

Answer (score 1):

I think KeyedCollection or Dictionary is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Collections.Hashtable`. It allow to store the heterogeneous type of object (a `Hashtable` can hold the multiple type of object).

Example:

```
System.Collections.Hashtable keyObjectMap = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
//Add into Hashtable
keyObjectMap["Key_1"] = "First String";
keyObjectMap["Key_2"] = "Second String";
//Add the value type
keyObjectMap["Key_3"] = 1;
keyObjectMap["Key_4"] = new object();

//Get value/object from Hashtable
string value = (string)keyObjectMap["Key_2"];
int intValue = (int)keyObjectMap["Key_3"];
```